# Angular 4 template in template

Tags: angular

I am trying to create custom slider. The problem is I have 2 sliders in my project with exactly the same functionality, but with two different html structures.
First slider item would look like this:

```html
<li> 
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <img src="url">
  <span>1000 items</span>
</li>
```

The second slider would look like this:

```html
<li> 
  <div>
    <img src="url">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>1234 count</span>
    <span>4321 count</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have solution when you render carousel in one template

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li *ngFor="#image of images">
      <h2>{{image.title}}</h2>
      <img src="{{image.url}}" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then you use it like this:

```html
<css-carousel [imageUrl]="url" [title]="title"></css-carousel>
```

But, in this case I would be able to use it only for html scenario.

Question:

Is it possible to pass custom html templates within one parent component, so I would use the same logic for different html markups?

Maybe it is possible to pass template itself?

Answer (score 0):

What if you create your component with @Input() for sources and going with ngFor loop

You can also loop though your components and attach themselves with input directive that will probably works

Comment: Yes, but it would work only for one html markup, I need to accomplish something like this:
<carousel>
  <slideType1></slideType1>
  <slideType2></slideType2>
</carousel>